# Iterate through DOM document with PHP

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I was simply trying to get all node names of an XML file in PHP by iterating through it. This is my attempt:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->loadXML("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?><user><name>Michael Taylor</name><offers>0</offers><address><street>Ringstreet 8</street><zip>1100</zip><city>Norther</city></address><credit>473.43</credit></user>");
$node = $doc->firstChild;

function iterateXML($node) {
    if($node->childNodes->length == 0) {
        echo $node->nodeName;
        return;
    }
    $children = $node->childNodes;
    foreach($children as $child) {
        iterateXML($child);
    }
}
iterateXML($node);
```

However, the output is

```
#text#text#text#text#text#text
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

My final plan was to add the name of the children to the name of the parent nodes seperated by "_", so the final output for the example above should be:

```
name
offers
address_street
address_zip
address_city
credit
```

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only the elements are nodes. You output the name of the nodes without children. In your XML that are text nodes only.

You could check the node type ... or use XPath:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?><user><name>Michael Taylor</name><offers>0</offers><address><street>Ringstreet 8</street><zip>1100</zip><city>Norther</city></address><credit>473.43</credit></user>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//*[count(*) = 0]') as $node) {
  var_dump($node->nodeName);
}
```

`*` matches elements nodes, `//*` means any element node in the document, `[count(*) = 0]` limits it to nodes without child element nodes.

Output:

```
string(4) "name"
string(6) "offers"
string(6) "street"
string(3) "zip"
string(4) "city"
string(6) "credit"
```

Comment: Great, but is it also possible with XPath to add the name of the child nodes to the name of the parent node? (see edited OP)

Comment: Here are several ways to to this. The nodes have a parentNode property. Here are `ancestor` and `parent` axis in XPath that can be used. But if you think about it `name` has a parent node `user`. Generic converts for XML to array are most of the time the wrong way to go. You loose information that you could still use by reading the the XML with Xpath directly.