# javascript - Find multi occurences inside a RegExp by Group

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I got this kind of HTML structure :

```
<p>TEST</p><ul><li>1 abc</li><li>2 def</li><li>3 ghi</li></ul>
```

And I want to get this :

```
 - Group 1 : TEST 
 - Group 2 : 1 abc 
 - Group 3 : 2 def  
 - Group 4 : 3 ghi
```

So I've write this reg exp :

```
<p>(.*?)<\/p>.*?<ul>(?(1)<li>(.*?)<\/li>*)<\/ul>
```

And the result is :

```
Match 1
Full match  0-50    `<p>TEST</p><ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></ul>`
Group 1.    3-7 `TEST`
Group 2.    19-40   `1</li><li>2</li><li>3`
```

Cf Regex101 : https://regex101.com/r/eoHtuI/1

This is write in PHP format but I may use it with Javascript also.
Any idea ?

Comment: Do you have to use a regex for this? DOM parsing would seem a lot more appropriate for the task.

Comment: I made a webscrap with that and I can't add any module due to my web hoster, so yes I have to use regex. 
By the way I also know that I can use more than one regex but I'm trying to do everything with just one to get a quicker code.

Answer (score 0):

You can split on each sequence of tags (for your sample input anyhow).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZhvaR))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<p>TEST</p><ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></ul>
HTML;

var_export(
    preg_split('~(?:<[^>]+>)+~', $html, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'TEST',
  1 => '1',
  2 => '2',
  3 => '3',
)
```

*Note, parsing html with regex is not recommended.  Here is a DomDocument/Xpath method (pulled mostly from https://stackoverflow.com/a/25695410/2943403)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Ycvs0))

```
$dom = new DOMDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//*[count(*) = 0]') as $node) {
  $result[] = $node->nodeValue;
}
var_export($result);  // same output as my regex method
```

Comment: If this doesn't satisfy for all of your use-cases, you'll need to improve your question and add some more sample inputs.